# Why while updating a dictionary getting None?

Tags: python, dictionary

[image]I am basically merging two dictionaries by using `update` method. The problem is when I merge in `python shell` it works but not in a file while executing.

```
v = {'customer_id': '9000', 'customer_name': 'Apple  Inc'}
b = {"a": "b"}

print v.update(b)
```

output of above is `None`

but its working in shell. What's my silly mistake? Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by _working in shell_? Even that outputs `None`.

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro check the image

Comment: That is because you printed the value of `v`. Where as the output for `v.update(b)` was nothing.

Comment: got it . Thanks guys :) for your patience

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`v.update(b)` is updating b *in place*. `v` is indeed updated, but the result of the update function is `None`, exactly what is printed out. If you do something like

```
v.update(b)
print v
```

you'll see `v` (updated)

Comment: after many years in python, still don't know why I still make this mistake, thanks

Answer (score 6):

The `update` function returns `None`. So

```
print v.update(b)  # this is printing out the return value of the update function.
```

To print out the updated value of the dict, just print the dict again

```
print v  # This will print the updated value of v
```